# I want to test an equation on arrays every unique combination of them, How could I do that using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, combinations

If I had 6 arrays, and each array has 6 values (NOT zeros), and I want to test an equation while assuming 3 arrays of them to be zero values every loop, how could I do that?

Example:

I have these 6 arrays:

```
$row_1 = array(a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4, e => 5, f => 6);
$row_2 = array(a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4, e => 5, f => 6);
$row_3 = array(a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4, e => 5, f => 6);
$row_4 = array(a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4, e => 5, f => 6);
$row_5 = array(a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4, e => 5, f => 6);
$row_6 = array(a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4, e => 5, f => 6);
```

Loop 1:

```
$row_1 = array(a => 0, b => 0, c => 0, d => 0, e => 0, f => 0);
$row_2 = array(a => 0, b => 0, c => 0, d => 0, e => 0, f => 0);
$row_3 = array(a => 0, b => 0, c => 0, d => 0, e => 0, f => 0);
$row_4 = array(a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4, e => 5, f => 6);
$row_5 = array(a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4, e => 5, f => 6);
$row_6 = array(a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4, e => 5, f => 6);
```

Loop 2:

```
$row_1 = array(a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4, e => 5, f => 6);
$row_2 = array(a => 0, b => 0, c => 0, d => 0, e => 0, f => 0);
$row_3 = array(a => 0, b => 0, c => 0, d => 0, e => 0, f => 0);
$row_4 = array(a => 0, b => 0, c => 0, d => 0, e => 0, f => 0);
$row_5 = array(a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4, e => 5, f => 6);
$row_6 = array(a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4, e => 5, f => 6);
```

Loop 3:

```
$row_1 = array(a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4, e => 5, f => 6);
$row_2 = array(a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4, e => 5, f => 6);
$row_3 = array(a => 0, b => 0, c => 0, d => 0, e => 0, f => 0);
$row_4 = array(a => 0, b => 0, c => 0, d => 0, e => 0, f => 0);
$row_5 = array(a => 0, b => 0, c => 0, d => 0, e => 0, f => 0);
$row_6 = array(a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4, e => 5, f => 6);
```

Loop 4:

```
$row_1 = array(a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4, e => 5, f => 6);
$row_2 = array(a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4, e => 5, f => 6);
$row_3 = array(a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4, e => 5, f => 6);
$row_4 = array(a => 0, b => 0, c => 0, d => 0, e => 0, f => 0);
$row_5 = array(a => 0, b => 0, c => 0, d => 0, e => 0, f => 0);
$row_6 = array(a => 0, b => 0, c => 0, d => 0, e => 0, f => 0);
```

Loop 5:

```
$row_1 = array(a => 0, b => 0, c => 0, d => 0, e => 0, f => 0);
$row_2 = array(a => 0, b => 0, c => 0, d => 0, e => 0, f => 0);
$row_3 = array(a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4, e => 5, f => 6);
$row_4 = array(a => 0, b => 0, c => 0, d => 0, e => 0, f => 0);
$row_5 = array(a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4, e => 5, f => 6);
$row_6 = array(a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4, e => 5, f => 6);
```

Loop 6:

```
$row_1 = array(a => 0, b => 0, c => 0, d => 0, e => 0, f => 0);
$row_2 = array(a => 0, b => 0, c => 0, d => 0, e => 0, f => 0);
$row_3 = array(a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4, e => 5, f => 6);
$row_4 = array(a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4, e => 5, f => 6);
$row_5 = array(a => 0, b => 0, c => 0, d => 0, e => 0, f => 0);
$row_6 = array(a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4, e => 5, f => 6);
```

Loop 7:

```
$row_1 = array(a => 0, b => 0, c => 0, d => 0, e => 0, f => 0);
$row_2 = array(a => 0, b => 0, c => 0, d => 0, e => 0, f => 0);
$row_3 = array(a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4, e => 5, f => 6);
$row_4 = array(a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4, e => 5, f => 6);
$row_5 = array(a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4, e => 5, f => 6);
$row_6 = array(a => 0, b => 0, c => 0, d => 0, e => 0, f => 0);
```

Loop 8:

```
$row_1 = array(a => 0, b => 0, c => 0, d => 0, e => 0, f => 0);
$row_2 = array(a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4, e => 5, f => 6);
$row_3 = array(a => 0, b => 0, c => 0, d => 0, e => 0, f => 0);
$row_4 = array(a => 0, b => 0, c => 0, d => 0, e => 0, f => 0);
$row_5 = array(a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4, e => 5, f => 6);
$row_6 = array(a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4, e => 5, f => 6);
```

...
...
...
...

Loop n:

...
...
...

Comment: @imsiso: He wants to do 6C3, or all combinations of 3 arrays from 6 (allowing no re-ordering).

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the purpose of this, but maybe something like this?

Instead of using $row1, $row2, $row3 etc I did these an array. Array is more flexibile to use in this situation. I did an example of how you could input your current variables into one array.

I've changed the code and I'm now using a diffrent approach. I use an object to store the array, and after that I use the stored array in the object to "reset" at each iteration of the loop. (OOP is the best way to do things anyway :-))

```
<?php
//Create a class to handle array
class arrayHandler {
    private $row = array();

    public function __construct(Array $row) {
        $this->row = $row; //Put array into object member
    }   

    public function loopArray($num=7, $numRandomEntries=3) {

        for ($nr = 0;$nr<intval($num);$nr++) { //Do seven loops

            //Get array stored in object
            $row = $this->row;

            //Get three random keys from the $row-array
            $randomEntries = array_rand($row, intval($numRandomEntries));

            //Set random entries elements to value 0
            foreach($randomEntries as $key) {
                $row[$key] = array_fill_keys(range('a', 'f'), 0);
            }

            $nNr = $nr+1;
            echo "row$nNr = " . print_r($row,true)."<hr />"; //For testing

        }

    }

}

//Your variables with stored arrays...
$row1 = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5, 'f' => 6);
$row2 = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5, 'f' => 6);
$row3 = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5, 'f' => 6);
$row4 = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5, 'f' => 6);
$row5 = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5, 'f' => 6);
$row6 = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5, 'f' => 6);

//Create ONE array from each variable above
$row = array();
$row[0] = $row1;
$row[1] = $row2;
$row[2] = $row3;
$row[3] = $row4;
$row[4] = $row5;
$row[5] = $row6;

//Create the object and do the looping
$ah = new arrayHandler($row);
$ah->loopArray();
?>
```

Comment: The result seems to be good, but why you did generate the arrays? I have a certain arrays those I need to apply the combination on them. Theres also a repeated combination rather than the array were 5 not six.

Comment: @m.rizeg - I aplologize for having 5 and not six. That is changed. I've also changed to OOP-style coding. I did an array of your current $row1, 2, 3 etc... so it would be easy to iterate through them and easy to randomly select select 3 of them. I inputted some code so you can use to combine your current row-variables. I hope this makes it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You basically want all combinations of 'values|no values'. There are 64 distinct combinations (`2^6`). A simple trick to get all combinations of two values is to use an integer, increment it by 1 to get the next combination, and then inspect its bit pattern:

```
$origArray = array(
  array_combine(range('a', 'f'), range(1, 6)),
  array_combine(range('a', 'f'), range(1, 6)),
  array_combine(range('a', 'f'), range(1, 6)),

  array_combine(range('a', 'f'), range(1, 6)),
  array_combine(range('a', 'f'), range(1, 6)),
  array_combine(range('a', 'f'), range(1, 6)),
);
$emptyArray = array_fill_keys(range('a', 'f'), 0);

define('COMBINATION_LENGTH', 6);

for($combination = pow(2, COMBINATION_LENGTH)-1; $combination >= 0; --$combination) {
  $currentCombinationArray = array();

  for($bitPosition = 0; $bitPosition < COMBINATION_LENGTH; ++$bitPosition) {
    $includeArray = ($combination >> (COMBINATION_LENGTH - $bitPosition - 1)) & 1;

    $currentCombinationArray[$bitPosition] = $includeArray ? $origArray[$bitPosition] : $emptyArray;
  }

  var_dump($currentCombinationArray);
}
```

This works, but I'm not sure how well it will perform.